# Storing big files on Operating System with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx, storage

I am having a dilemma between a couple of options:
I have a video app in NodeJS, in which currently I save big
 video files inside a folder called files which is inside 
my main node folder, and I reference them with MongoDB
(inside my MongoDB documents there are strings which lead to them).

I am starting to worry this is not the right way as this folder
is getting big. I read alternatives like Nginx 
and even storing the big files directly on my MongoDB database,
but is it even necessary? efficiency-wise and organized-wise, which is the best? Thanks.

Btw: I do not stream these big files to the client, they are not public files. But I do work with them in some other ways.

Comment: If they are private, storing them in a folder is the best way.
If they were public, I would advice you install nginx and run your server behind it because node.js is NOT designed for serving static files. (You will get errors when serving a lot of static file with node,  so running app behind nginx is always good.)

Comment: Isn't there a risk, say if my Operating System is windows and this folder size is getting above 5 terabyte..

Comment: Yeah it's always risk, in that case you can jump to a scalable cloud system like Amazon.

Comment: They'll have to cost. btw, the videos are dynamically downloaded through request module to my video folder. Can NodeJS handle it well?